# Cannot find name 'HTMLInputElement' typescript

Tags: typescript

Which types module can provide definition files for DOM nodes? I thought this definition would be bundled with installing TypeScript, but it was not and I could not find it in popular libraries, like React, that depend on it either. Any insight?

```
  private textInput: HTMLInputElement; // error message: 'Cannot find name "HTMLInputElement"'
  private userId: number;
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true,
    "useCache": false,
    "emitRequireType": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share your `tsconfig.json`, also, while images are nice, the url might break in the future, please also add this code as text to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I just answered that (an hour ago) in another post (^^^ link above), the only differences are that he was targeting `ES2016` while you target `esnext`, and that he looked for `document`/`window` and you're looking for `HTMLInputElement` which are part of the `DOM` lib which is missing.

Comment: Resolved, thank you!